# The script does not run without flags

Tags: bash, curl

Wrote a script, the main task of which is to upload and download files.

```
#!/bin/bash

fileUpload() {
  local filepath=$1
  local transfer_path=$2
  local url

  url=$(curl --progress-bar --upload-file "$filepath" "https://transfer.sh/$transfer_path")

  echo "$url"
}

printOutUpload() {
  local filepath=$1
  local url

  echo "Uploading $filepath"

  url=$(fileUpload "$filepath")

  echo "Transfer File URL: $url"
}

fileDownload() {
  local destination=$1
  local url=$2
  local file_name=$3

  curl -# "https://transfer.sh/$url/$file_name" -o "$destination/$file_name"
}

printOutDownload() {
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Success!"
  else
    echo "Error: There was a problem downloading the file."
  fi
}

while getopts "d:" opt; do
  case $opt in
    d)
      printOutDownload
      fileDownload "$2" "$3" "$4"
      ;;
    \?)
      echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2
      exit 1
      ;;
  esac
done
```

With flag -d script download single file from the transfer:

```
./script -d ./tests HJkv1I test.txt
```

Without it should upload files:

```
./script test.txt test1.txt
```

One by one, each of these functions work correctly, but I can't get them to work in one script - If I add the -d flag, downloading is working, but upload not, its do nothing

Comment: Why, specifically, do you think it _should_ do anything if there's no `-d`, and what's the thing you expect it to do? The `while` loop only calls `printOutDownload` or `fileDownload` when it's present. If we don't know what you think _should_ happen, and _why_ you think it should happen, the question is both unclear and broad (insofar as it's not being narrowed down to ask only about the specific place actual and expected behavior diverge).

Comment: What's your question? We're not here to do your debugging for you. You might try looking at [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert. Please read [ask] and [mre].

Comment: @Charles Duffy
i mean, without flag -d, I don't understand how by default (without flags) use upload function

Comment: @lunnyj, ...it _doesn't_ use the upload function by default without flags. Or do you mean that you _want to_ do that, and don't understand how to make it happen? If that's what you want to know, you should ask it explicitly; don't make us guess what you mean.

Comment: In general, inside your `while` loop iterating over arguments, you should just set variables indicating which flags were seen; then, _after the loop exits_, inspect those flags and take an appropriate action.

Comment: It would be much better to use `-d` and `-u` to download and upload or even have them as subcommand are they are not optional

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a flag when processing the arguments. Then after the `getopts` loop, use an `if` statement to perform an upload or download depending on the flag.

```
direction=up

while getopts "d:" opt; do
  case $opt in
    d) direction=down
      ;;
    \?)
      echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2
      exit 1
      ;;
  esac
done

shift (($OPTIND-1))

if [[ $direction == up ]]
then
    printOutUpload
    fileUpload "$@"
else
    printOutDownload
    fileDownload "$@"
fi
```